# Conormal bundle and lagrangian submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, tangent-bundle

> Let $Q_1^{n_1},Q_2^{n_2}$ be smooth manifolds, $\phi:Q_1\to Q_2$ a smooth map and:
>   $$R_\phi:=\{(x, \xi, y,\eta)\mid y=\phi(x), \xi=(d\phi)^*\eta\}\subset T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2$$
>   $$\text{graph}(\phi)=\{(q,\phi(q))\mid q\in Q_1\}\subset Q_1\times Q_2$$
>   verifiy that $R_\phi$ is a Lagrangian submanifold and describe the relation between $R_\phi$ and the conormal bundle $N^*\text{graph}(\phi)$.

I was able prove that $R_\phi$ is Lagrangian, but I don't know where the conormal bundle fits into the picture. Since $R_\phi$ is Lagrangian, it has dimension $n_1+n_2$, while $N^*\text{graph}(\phi)$ has dimension $n_2$. Is the conormal bundle embbeded in $R_\phi$, maybe? If so,  why is this interesting?

Comment: Given submanifolds $X \subset Y$ with $X$ embedded (to simplify),$$N^*X := \{ (y, \xi) \in T^*Y : y \in X, \xi \in T^*_y Y, \left. \xi \right|_{T_y X} = 0 \}.$$ It is a bundle over $X$ of rank the codimension of $X$ in $Y$; hence the dimension of the total space $N^*X$ is $$\mathrm{dim} X + \mathrm{codim}_Y(X) = \mathrm{dim}(Y) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{dim}(T^*Y) .$$
Consequently, chances are that $N^*X$ is a Lagrangian subset of $T^*Y$. I suggest you compare $R_{\phi}$ and $N^*\mathrm{graph}(\phi)$ under the standard isomorphism $T^*Q_1 \times T^*Q_2 \simeq T^*(Q_1 \times Q_2)$.

Comment: @JordanPayette, how about this: let $\Gamma_\phi:=\text{graph}(\phi)$. If $(x,y)$ are coord. for $Q_1\times Q_2$, $\Gamma_\phi$ has coord. $x$, therefore $T_{(q,\phi(q))}\Gamma_\phi=\text{span}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)$. So basically $$N^*\Gamma_\phi=\{(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mid y=\phi(x),\,(\xi,\eta)|_{\text{span}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)}=0\}$$ This last condition means $\xi=0$ so $N^*\Gamma_\phi$ is made of points $(x,0,\phi(x),\eta)$. So there is a diffeo $N^*\Gamma_\phi\to R_\phi$,  $(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mapsto (x,(d\phi)^*\eta,\phi(x),\eta)$ with natural inverse.

Comment: We have $$T_{(q, \phi(q))}\Gamma_{\phi} = \mathrm{span}\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + \phi_{\ast}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \right\} $$ The conormal condition is  $$\xi(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}) + \eta(\phi_{\ast}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}) = 0 \; i.e. \; \xi^i = - (\phi^{\ast}\eta)^i $$
There are symplectic diffeos $$(T^{\ast}(Q_1 \times Q_2), d\lambda_{12}) \simeq (T^{\ast}Q_1 \times T^{\ast}Q_2, d\lambda_1 \oplus d\lambda_2) \simeq (T^{\ast}Q_1 \times T^{\ast}Q_2, d\lambda_1 \oplus (-d\lambda_2)),$$ the latter map being $(x, \xi, y, \eta) \mapsto (x, \xi, y, - \eta)$.

Comment: @JordanPayette How did you find that $T_{(q,\phi(q))}\Gamma_\phi=\text{span}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}+d\phi\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\right)$? I'm thinking that if I messed up with $T_{(q,\phi(q))}\Gamma_\phi$, I probably messed up with $T_{m,n}R_\phi$ in the first part of the exercise too.

Comment: Essentially derive a curve $c(t) = (q(t), \phi(q(t))$ where $q(t)$ is a function which, in local coordinates on $Q_1$, only varies along the $i$-th direction, say. Then $c'(0) = \partial_{x_i} + \phi_* \partial_{x_i}$.

Comment: @JordanPayette I'm redoing my calculations for $TR_\phi$. I thought about using curves like you did, but I got confused with the term $(d\phi)^*\eta$ in $(x,(d\phi)^*\eta,\phi(x), \eta)$. I also tried to find $d\iota$ explicitly for the inclusion $\iota:(x, \eta)\mapsto (x,(d\phi)^*\eta,\phi(x),\eta)$ but the calculatons seem cumbersome, so I still hope  the curve strategy is possible.

Comment: Compute in coordinates & substitute $\xi = (d\phi)^*\eta$ and $y = \phi(x)$ into $\sum_j (d\xi_j \wedge dx^j - d\eta_j \wedge dy^j)$. Schematically, you'll get something like $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} \eta dx \wedge dx +  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} d\eta \wedge dx - d\eta \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} dx$. The last two terms cancel, while the first term vanishes for (anti)symmetry reasons of the hessian and of the wedge. I voluntarily leave you the task to work out the details, as they are very common in differential geometry.

Comment: Thanks, @JordanPayette, I've written a detailed answer, which I think is correct now. By the way, just to get it off my chest: I already took a course on smooth manifolds and thought I understood them, but now that I'm studying Symplectic Geometry I realize I was wrong. On the bright side, I'm starting to sense what manifolds are really about and things are making much more sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't worry about that, it is perfectly normal to truly understand a subject only once we try to apply it elsewhere, when we have to fill the 'gaps'/implicit steps in someone's explanation. At least, I (still) am in the same position. However it is primordial to *really* (and another *really* if necessary) try hard to fill the 'gaps' by ourselves for true understanding to emerge, especially if we plan on doing research eventually. In any case, good work and good continuation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to thank Jordan Payette for the crucial help.

Locally, $R_\phi$ is represented by points $(x,(d\phi)^*\eta,\phi(x),\eta)$, hence it is parametrized by coordinates $x,\eta$. This proves that $R_\phi$ is embedded in $T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2$ and has dimension $n_1+n_2$ (i.e., half the dimension of the ambient space). So in order to prove that $R_\phi$ is Lagrangian, it suffices to show that it is isotropic, i.e., $i^*\omega=0$, where $i:R_\phi\hookrightarrow T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2$ with $ (x,\eta)\mapsto (x,(d\phi)^*\eta,\phi(x),\eta)$ is the inclusion.

If $u(x,\eta):=(d\phi)_x^*(\eta)$, notice that:
\begin{align*}
u_i&=u(x,\eta)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)=\eta\left(d\phi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}\eta_j\frac{\partial \phi_j}{\partial x_i}\\
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k}-\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_i}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}\eta_j\frac{\partial^2 \phi_j}{\partial x_k\partial x_i}-\eta_j\frac{\partial^2 \phi_j}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}=0\\
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial \eta_k}&=\frac{\partial \phi_k}{\partial x_i}
\end{align*}

Hence:
\begin{align*}
i^*\omega &=i^*\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}dx_i\wedge d\xi_i-\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}dy_j\wedge d\eta_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}dx_i\wedge du_i-\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}d\phi_j\wedge d\eta_j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}dx_i\wedge\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n_1}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k}dx_k+\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial\eta_j}d\eta_j\right)-\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}\frac{\partial\phi_j}{\partial x_i}dx_i\right)\wedge d\eta_j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}\sum_{k=1}^{n_1}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k}dx_i\wedge dx_k+\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}\sum_{j=1}^{n_2}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial\eta_j}-\frac{\partial\phi_j}{\partial x_i}\right)}_{=0}dx_i\wedge d\eta_j\\
&=\sum_{1\leq i<k\leq n_1}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_k}-\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_i}\right)}_{=0}dx_i\wedge dx_k=0
\end{align*}

We prove that $R_\phi$ is diffeomorphic to $N^*\Gamma_\phi$, where $\Gamma_\phi:=\text{graph}(\phi)$. If $i':\Gamma_\phi\hookrightarrow Q_1\times Q_2$ with $x\mapsto (x,\phi(x))$ is the inclusion, we have $di'\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+d\phi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)$, which means $T_{(x,\phi(x))}\Gamma_\phi=\text{span}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+d\phi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\right)$. Moreover, $T^*(Q_1\times Q_2)\simeq T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2$ and $N^*\Gamma_\phi=\{(x,\xi)\in T^*(Q_1\times Q_2)\mid x\in \Gamma_\phi,\,\xi|_{T_x\Gamma_\phi}\equiv 0\}$. Therefore:

\begin{align*}
N^*\Gamma_\phi &\simeq\{(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mid (x,y)\in \Gamma_\phi,\,(\xi,\eta)|_{T_{(x,y)}\Gamma_\phi}\equiv 0\}\\
&=\left\{(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mid y=\phi(x),\,\xi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)+\eta\left(d\phi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\right)=0\,\forall i\right\}\\
&=\left\{(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mid y=\phi(x),\,(\xi+(d\phi)^*\eta)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)=0\,\forall i\right\}\\
&=\{(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mid y=\phi(x),\,\xi=-(d\phi)^*\eta\}\subset T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2
\end{align*}
Since $f:(x,\xi,y,\eta)\mapsto (x,\xi,y,-\eta)$ is a diffeomorphism (in fact a symplectomorphism) from $(T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2,\omega_1\oplus\omega_2)$ to $(T^*Q_1\times T^*Q_2,\omega_1\oplus-\omega_2)$, we get a diffeomorphism:
$$\left.f\right|_{N^*\Gamma_\phi}:N^*\Gamma_\phi\to R_\phi$$